# onEdit simple trigger never seems to be triggered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've been using `OnEdit` for some time and its been working great - however just now ive came accross a problem - basically when column 6 (f) is edited I want it to check the value - if it is "In Progress" I want it to then run a function to send an email, when I debug this - it works great exactly as I want it to, however when im not debugging it never seems to run.

```
var summary = ss.getSheetByName("Summary")
var data = summary.getRange(4, 1, summary.getLastRow(), summary.getLastColumn());
var learnerObjects = getRowsData(summary, data);
var lastrow = summary.getLastRow();

function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var CellRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var CellColumn = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Summary"){
    if (CellColumn == 6){
      var learner = learnerObjects[CellRow-4];
      var status = learner.status;
      if (status == "In Progress"){
        var enrolmentdate = learner.enrolmentDateDdmmyyyy;
        var surname = learner.surname;
        var firstname = learner.firstName;
        var qualification = learner.qualification;
        var company = learner.company;
        messagePT3 = firstname + " " + surname + " from " + company + " doing " + qualification + " has been added to your tracker.";
        sendTrackerEmail(messagePT3);
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Email has been sent to Assessor regarding new learner', 'Assessor Notified', 3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the main code for it, when debugging as I say it works fine, however when im not debugging it never seems to be triggered, is there any other ways for me to do this?

I have data validation on column F however this limits the cells to "Completed", "Withdrawn", "Suspended" or "In Progress" - this shouldnt have an effect should it?

I know that `onEdit` is being triggered as I use it for monitoring changes to certain parts of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `onEdit()` trigger is a so called "simple trigger" that has a limited field of action.
Since it runs automatically and silently under the authority of the active user it can't do anything that requires authorization, for example it can't send emails !

The solution is simple : change your function name to something else (myOnEdit for example) and set an installable onEdit trigger to run that function.(menu ressource/current script trigger/create new trigger in the script editor.)

This time it will be executed as you (you'll be sending the emails) when anyone edits the spreadsheet.

Documentation on that subject is [available here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers#Simple).