# Checking checkbox does not open sidebar window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

[image]

As a follow up to [Trigger function by checking checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935138/trigger-function-by-checking-checkbox), I have a sheet with checkboxes in the first column.  I would like to be able to open a ui sidebar by checking a box? Right now I have a function popupRow that creates the sidebar and starts with:

```
function popupRow() {

      Logger.log('popupRow1');
  var id = 'vvvvvvvvvVYpeOmRn6lVk-xxxxxxxx'
 var sheet =    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('mysheet');
 var headerRow = sheet.getFrozenRows();

      Logger.log('popupRow2');
  ....
```

Following what I saw in the previous question I tried:

```
function onEdit(e){
 if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.columnEnd == 1 && e.range.rowStart <= 2000) {

    Logger.log('ONEDIT');
    popupRow();
```

The sidebar does not open and the logs show:

```
[19-03-02 10:30:23:034 EST] ONEDIT
[19-03-02 10:30:23:034 EST] popupRow1
```

Execution does not get to the line containing:

```
      Logger.log('popupRow2');
```

Why not? How can I get this working?

Comment: You're using unauthorized functions. Review the restrictions associated with simple triggers. You can view these restrictions in documentation, and view the errors your script is throwing in Stackdriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Script - OnEdit problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333232/google-script-onedit-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Open Sidebar and/or Dialog with Checkbox or Menu

Codes.gs:

```
function onOpen() {
  menu();
}

function menu() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem('Insert CheckBoxes', 'insertCheckboxes')
  .addItem('Create OnEdit Trigger', 'createOnEditTrigger')
  .addItem('Open Dialog', 'openTheDialog')
  .addItem('Open Sidebar', 'openTheSidebar')
  .addItem('Delete Trigger', 'deleteOnEditTrigger')
  .addToUi();
}

function openTheDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example1').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Example 1 HTML');
}

function openTheSidebar() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('example1').evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function getColumnHeight(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var lastrow=sh.getLastRow();
  if(lastrow==0)return 0;
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,col,lastrow,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  while(vA.length>0 && vA[vA.length-1][0].length==0){
    vA.splice(vA.length-1,1);
  }
  return vA.length;
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function getRowColumn() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var rObj={row:rg.getColumn() ,column:rg.getRow()};
  return rObj;
}

function getCellA1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveCell();
  var rObj={A1:rg.getA1Notation()};
  return rObj;
}

function onCheckOpenSideBar(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet1')return;
  if(e.range.rowStart==2 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheSidebar();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart==3 && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    if(e.value=='TRUE') {
      openTheDialog();
      e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart).setValue("FALSE");
    }
  }
}

function createOnEditTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onCheckOpenSideBar').forSpreadsheet('Spreadsheet ID').onEdit().create();
}

function insertCheckboxes() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(2,1,2).insertCheckboxes();
}

function deleteOnEditTrigger() {
  var tA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    if(tA[i].getHandlerFunction()=='onCheckOpenSideBar') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(tA[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Script.html:

```
<script>
  function getRowCol(){
    $('#rc').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
      $('#rc').val(rObj.row + ',' + rObj.column);
      $('#rc').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    })
    .getRowColumn();
  }
  function getCellA1(){
    $('#A1').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
      $('#A1').val(rObj.A1);
      $('#A1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    })
    .getCellA1();
  }
  function getColumnHeight(){
    $('#colheight').css('background-color','#ffff00');
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(h){
      $('#colheight').val(h);
      $('#colheight').css('background-color','#ffffff');
    })
    .getColumnHeight();
  }
</script>
```

css.html:

```
<style>
body {background-color:#ffffff;}
input{padding:2px;margin:2px;}
</style>
```

res.html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

example1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('res') ?>
    <?!= include('css') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input id="A1" type="text" placeholder="A1Notation" size="6" /><input type="button" value="Cell A1" onClick="getCellA1();" />
   <br /><input id="rc" type="text" placeholder="Row , Column" size="6" /><input type="button" value="Row,Column " onClick="getRowCol();" />
   <br /><input id="colheight" type="text" placeholder="Column Height" size="6" /><input type="button" value="Column Height" onClick="getColumnHeight();" />
   <?!= include('script') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a lot of interesting code here. I haven't got it working yet though  (just added onCheckOpenSideBar and openTheSidebar)